# Is it possible to use subcaption inside a minipage?

Tags: subfloats, minipage, subcaption

I have tried formulations of using `subcaption` inside `minipage`--`subcaption` and `subcaptionbox`.  I have also look at some threads but couldn't find anything doing what I needed.

Please note that this `minipage` is enclosed in a `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = parens, labelsep = space, font = small}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{A frictionless ball in a semi-circle. \label{semicircle}
      [.5\linewidth]{\includestandalone{semicircle}}
    \subcaptionbox{Close up of the forces on the frictionless ball.
      \label{exam2triangle}
      [.5\linewidth]{\includestandalone{exam2triangle}}
    \captionof{figure}[Frictionless Ball on a Semi-Circle]{A frictionless ball
      oscillating on a semi-circle.}
    \label{exam2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

This was my most recent failed attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally I wouldn't suggest this, but this seems to be a case in which the `H` specifier (from, for example, the `float` package) might be handy to suppress flotation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = parens, labelsep = space, font = small}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{A frictionless ball in a semi-circle.}
    {\includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}}\quad
    \subcaptionbox{Close up of the forces on the frictionless ball.}
     {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image-b}}
    \caption[Frictionless Ball on a Semi-Circle]{A frictionless ball
      oscillating on a semi-circle.}
    \label{exam2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I thought the figure environment didn't work in the `tcolorbox` environment.

Comment: It doesn't as a float, but the `H` specifier suppresses floating.

Comment: @HarishKumar yes, it was time for a change :-)

Answer (score 11):

Yes, it is possible, just use `\captionsetup{type=figure}` inside your `minipage` to tell the (sub)caption package to treat this `minipage` as `figure`, at least from `caption`s point of view. Afterwards use ordinary captioning commands like `\caption` and `\subcaptionbox`, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = parens, labelsep = space, font = small}
\begin{document}
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \captionsetup{type=figure} % -- This line added
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{A frictionless ball in a semi-circle. \label{semicircle}}
      [.5\linewidth]{\includegraphics{semicircle}}
    \subcaptionbox{Close up of the forces on the frictionless ball.
      \label{exam2triangle}}
      [.5\linewidth]{\includegraphics{exam2triangle}}
    \caption[Frictionless Ball on a Semi-Circle]{A frictionless ball
      oscillating on a semi-circle.}
    \label{exam2}
  \end{minipage}
\end{document}
```