# Problems using minipage and subcaptionbox to display subfigures

Tags: subfloats, minipage

In order to display multiple images I'm trying to build them in using `subcaptionbox` in minipages. This setup might be weird, yet the neither the usual subfigure nor minipage setup as suggested in [Is it possible to use subcaption inside a minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127379/is-it-possible-to-use-subcaption-inside-a-minipage) helped me solve the following problems:

1. The "subcaptions" are not numbered with a, b, c and so on.
2. The "subcaptions" are displayed above the figures. I prefer having them below the pictures.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[BCOR10.00mm,twoside,openright,DIV13,a4paper,fleqn,halfparskip,headsepline,11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat = parens, labelsep = space, font = small}\usepackage{float}
                \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}\usepackage{subfig}\usepackage{mwe,subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{figure}[H]
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
        \captionsetup{type=figure}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{H Point 1}
        {\includegraphics[height=.5\textwidth]{Point1_H.png}}
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage}%%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \subcaptionbox{V Point 1}
        {\includegraphics[height=.5\textwidth]{Point1_V.png}}
    \vspace{4ex}
  \end{minipage}
    \caption[Obs Point 1]{Obs Point 1}
  \label{OP1}
    \end{figure}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image: This is the outcome]

I really hope you can help me. I cant find the error by myself.

Answer (score 2):

You are using your environments in wrong order: First, `figure` should be the outermost one if you want a floating environment.  Then, you can *either* use the `subfigure` environment provided by `subcaption.sty` and the `\caption`command *or* `\subcaptionbox` directly inside the `figure`.  Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{%
  labelformat = parens,
  labelsep = space,
  font = small
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \caption{H Point 1}
  \end{subfigure}%
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}
    \caption{V Point 1}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption[Obs Point 1]{Obs Point 1}
  \label{OP1}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \subcaptionbox{H Point 1}[0.5\textwidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
  }%
  \subcaptionbox{V Point 1}[0.5\textwidth][c]{%
    \includegraphics[height=3cm,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
  }
  \caption[Obs Point 2]{Obs Point 2}
  \label{OP2}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Well, to be honest, this didn't solve my problem. I copied your suggestion and end up with a screwed outcome

Comment: @FMerk - I thought you know how to adjust the values.  I've updated my answer, maybe you want to play with this as a template.